# Linkedin Follow Button not showing properly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe, linkedin-api

I've set the Linkedin Follow button within a hidden element, so only when you hover an icon, the hidden element becomes visible and button is shown.

Problem is that in Firefox v35.0.1 the followers number is shown not on the same row, as if there is no enough space on the same row. Look at the photo:

[image]

When I'm expecting the source code it seems the iframe is being set width and height in the moment of becoming visible (on hover) and then (on blur) its width/height is set back to 0. In Chrome the iframe has a constant width/height, which doesn't change on hover.

I tried to set the iframe width with css, which didn't work because when I expected the code it turned out there is another iframe in the Linkedin iframe and the internal iframe has again wrong dimensions.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: when I set the wrapping element to be visible all is good, so this seems to cause the problem, but how can I fix it?

UPDATE 2: You can see the problem yourself: [link](https://linkedindemo-todorpr.c9.io/) (make sure open it in Firefox!)

EDIT: Someone edited my post removing Linkedin tag from it, but I truly believe that this is more their issue than Firefox's or CSS, as there is something within their javascript that adds the width/height to the button iframe and adds them wrong. Also in IE the same issue appears. I added the button twice - first time as it was and second time in a visible wrapper and it's obvious that in the visible wrapper all is OK, though in the hidden wrapper is broken.

UPDATE 3: I realized that the button iframe width is the same as its `#body` element's 'min-width: 57px', so if Linkedin team correct that `min-width` to let's say `120px` this may solve this problem.

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ example with your code?

Comment: I tried, but http://jsfiddle.net/ didn't allow me to put script in the html area and http://jsbin.com/ throws a "Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document'" error.

Comment: Todo, can you paste your source code in the question, then?

Comment: OK, I could isolate just this piece of code: https://linkedindemo-todorpr.c9.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is here :

[image: problem in firefox]

in firefox the loaded width are 2px in the element but in webkit(chrome and opera) are 106px.

the style is not making enough width to show elements in one line.
and here is answer :

```
    .social-details {
    width: 195px;
    /* float: left; */
    position: absolute;
    left: -120px;
    top: -7px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 11px 10px 8px 10px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

and

```
#social .social-linkedin:hover .social-details {
visibility: visible;
}
```

its allow the element load with 106px of width and it is hidden to users.

Comment: That's not true. Look at the button in the visible wrapper... you see it renders properly and has the same CSS as the button in the invisible wrapper, just the display property is different. + I don't have `#body` element.

Comment: body element is in the frame that load from linkedin. i will edit my answer soon with right answer.

Comment: You are wrong, mate. You can not apply CSS to HTML that is loaded in an iframe, unless you have control over the page loaded in the iframe.

Comment: the main problem is in the loaded inline style in firefox. i think we can correct this with javascript styling after loading.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, but I doubt we can correct iframe in another iframe from another domain (CORS problem).

Comment: i can add some style to element when they loading is complete and in local. i test it and say to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69812/discussion-between-hosein-and-todo).